# Can I get variable in constructor when statically call method of class?

Tags: php, oop

Can I check $param value in __construct and set new value in self::$param?

```
Class::method($param);

class Class {    

    public function __construct() {


    }

    public static function method($param) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it if you have a static member of the class just like this

```
class Class 
{    
    public static $member;

    public function __construct() {

          // Here you can get or set the static::$member
    }

    public static function method($param = static::$member) {


    }
}
```

Now if you call the method with an arguments, it takes the value of the argument, otherwise it takes the value of static::$param

```
Class::$member = 123;
Class::method();  // $param = 123
Class::method(456); // $param = 456
```